# How to know which users have seen certain post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm developing a Django web app in which I need to know which users have seen certain posts, I'd like to do this by adding a 'seen_by' field in the Post model, but I really don't know if it's possible to do it that way.

The only way I can think of doing this is by making a function in which if an user visits an object, somehow send information to this object that the user visited it.

Obviously I'm relatively new to programming in Django, I don't know if this can be done through signals or how, but I'd very much appreciate any help or advice specifically for this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only way I can think of doing this is by making a function in which if an user visits an object, somehow send information to this object that the user visited it.

Yes, you can add a `ManyToManyField` to your post to keep track of the users that have seen that post:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    # …
    seen_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    )
```

then in the view where you show the `Post`, you can add the user to the `seen_by` users of that post:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def post_detail(request, post_pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    post.seen_by.add(request.user)
    # …
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'post': post})
```

or in a `DetailView`, you can for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object.seen_by.add(self.request.user)
        return context
```

This will thus not add a user if the user has not been logged in.

Comment: I'm showing this in a DetailView. 
The `@login_required` decorator can be circumvented by saying in the same function that if not logged in, no changes should be made?